# Python.Type Error

Tags: python, type-error

У меня есть запрос вида `cur.fetchone()[0]` , где ноль это цифра нужного элемента из списка, всего мне их нужно 3, я делаю отдельно запросы `cur.fetchone()[0]`, затем `cur.fetchone()[1]` ну и `cur.fetchone()[2]` и всё хорошо, но потом я пытаюсь  впихать эти результаты в текст вот таким образом:

```
res = '&#128203;Имя: ' + cur.fetchone()[0] + '\n&#9654;Ваш уровень: ' + cur.fetchone()[1] + '\n&#128176;Мяукоины: ' + cur.fetchone()[2]
```

Мне выдаёт TypeError. Как быть? Я уж пробовал в `str()` всё возможное, но не помогло, прошу помощи

Comment: Желательно привести полный текст ошибки для начала.

Comment: Exception has occurred: TypeError
'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
  File "C:\Users\andre\Desktop\acc.py", line 35, in calcm
    res = '&#128203;Имя: ' + cur.fetchone()[0] + '\n&#9654;Ваш уровень: ' + cur.fetchone()[1] + '\n&#128176;Мяукоины: ' + cur.fetchone()[2]
  File "C:\Users\andre\Desktop\Meow Manager.py", line 165, in <module>
    ans = calcm(fq)

Comment: Вы понимаете, что каждый раз вводя `cur.fetchone()`, вы снова и снова вызываете этот метод? Лучше сначала просто получите все значения из query, а затем подставляйте их. например так: `name, level, wealth = cur.fetchone()[0,1,2]`. и далее `print ("Имя" + name)`.

Comment: Я не знал про возможность cur.fetchone()[0,1,2]  Не знал, что так можно перечислять

Большое спасибо за твой ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
row = cur.fetchone()
if row:
    res = '&#128203;Имя: {}\n&#9654;Ваш уровень: {}\n&#128176;Мяукоины: {}\n'.format(*row)
```

Comment: Exception has occurred: TypeError
can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: Всё, заработало